# Function Range.Copyfromrecordset do not shows right columns

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, adodb

I fill a recordset from a simple query with ADO and when manually printing it's all good and clear but when i try to transfer the Recordset in the Sheet's table only 3 columns are filled out of 4.

That's the only method i use and always worked.
I changed Range, pointed outside a table, used a single cell and a bigger range than what my query will return. All I got was 3 columns.

```vb
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim conn As Object
    Set conn = openCon 'other function I assure to works
    Dim rst As Object
    Dim query As String
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.RECORDSET")

'I don't think the problem is here but i really don't know what it could be
    If ws.Range("tabArts").Rows.Count > 1 Then
        ws.Range("tabArts").Rows.Delete
    Else
        ws.Range("tabArts").ClearContents
    End If

    query = ""
    query = query & "SELECT art.code , "
    query = query & "       art.descr, "
    query = query & "       Sum (tb1.qty) 'Qty', "
    query = query & "       tb1.serials "
'serials is defined as NON NULL, so it's an empty string if not written
    query = query & "FROM   tb1  "
    query = query & "       LEFT OUTER JOIN articles art "
    query = query & "                    ON tb1.idart = art.id "
    query = query & "GROUP BY code, Descr, serials"
'This query return a full 4 columns table with 15 rows

    rst.activeconnection = conn
    rst.Open query
    ws.Range("tabArts").CopyFromRecordset rst
'tabArts is a table with same query's headers 


    rst.Close
    conn.Close
```

Comment: What is the size of range "tabArts" ?

Comment: 4 columns, address : $D$6:$G$6

Comment: Welcome to SO. The missing colum, is it always the same one?

Comment: Have You tried to paste the recordset into just 1 cell? I mean for example `ws.Range("D6").CopyFromRecordset rst`

Comment: @foxfire-and-burns-and-burns I tried to "select * " and now it shows me 9 columns out of 140; the column "serials" is still not shown.

Comment: @teamothy yes, I tried exactly the same line you suggested obtaining the same result

Comment: Maybe from another side - have You tried to put all the column names in brackets? ( [tb1].[serials] )

Comment: If you do `Debug.Print rst.Fields.Count` after `rst.Open query` what do you get?

Comment: @Teamoty I tried just now and nothing changed :(

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns the count is 4, there is nothing bad with the recordset. I even tried to set a simple 'NNN' instead of field serials and they simply does not show themselves, BUT the Recordset itself is ok. I can see every serial if I loop rst, but i don't want to loop and i'd like to understand WHY is this happening

Comment: A hidden column somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code before rst.open

```
rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rst.CursorType = adOpenStatic
```